# Collapsible Views

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to achieve the following. My app will have some views. All of the views are simple textViews which when clicked will be redirected to another activity. But the last view needs to expand to show hidden views. the sub views can further have more sub categories. To be more clear i have attached an image to explain this more detail. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUCvV.jpg)

So here views 1 - 3 are normal text views. view 4 has sub categories sub view 4.1 till 4.3. these can have further sub categories like 4.1.1, 4.1.2. Also when 4.1 is expanded and user clicks on 4.2 to expand it, 4.1 should automatically collapse then 4.2 should expand. I tried using expandable list view for this purpose buy the rest of my views are not list items. Please help me acheive this. Right now m using text vies and using its visibility to hide or show the views. This is not getting me the desired result. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use ListView to achieve this perfeclty, else you have to view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE).

Comment: @shahzainali ListView or expandable ListView??? Could you point me to some tutorials or code snippets

Answer (score 0):

It is expandable listview you can use following tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

and for to collapse automatically all except selected one use this code

```
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;
private ExpandableListView lv; //your expandable listview
...

lv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                lv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

Hopefully it will fullfil your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with NLevelListView  best example for multilevel parent and child listview , But need to make data list according below example of Github

https://github.com/triggs/NLevelExpandableListView/tree/master/src/com/twocentscode/nlevelexpandablelistview